# Sci-fi on Mars where a robot angel fights a train

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a pair of surreal sci-fi books, probably from the mid to late 90s,
with a comdemy tone.

Both set on Mars, featuring the following (not sure which book contains which bit):

- A battle between a robot angel and a train
- human furniture
- a green (time travelling?) scientist with plant DNA
- a character walking through the desert, with the prose gradually turning to pre swearing as she becomes more dehydrated

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are these books part of the same series? If they aren't, you should post a separate question for each one.

Comment: As it's not clear which set of details applies to which book, how could that be done? Ask the same question twice? Or, wait until it gets one answer, and then ask again with the leftovers?

Comment: I don't get the word "comdemy". Is it just a typo for something (condemny? condemnatory?) or (more interestingly)  maybe some sf terminology I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is absolutely [Desolation Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desolation_Road) and the follow up novel [Ares Express](https://www.goodreads.com/series/83986) by [Ian McDonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_McDonald_(British_author)).

[image]

> both are set on Mars

✅ Yes, however it wasn't obvious to me reading Desolation Road that it was set on Mars until near the end. I can't remember if that was deliberate on the part of the author or not.

> A battle between a robot angel and a train

> ✅ Happens towards the end of the first book

> a green (time travelling?) scientist with plant DNA

✅ Appears in the first book, and yes, time travelling

> a character walking through the desert, with the prose gradually turning to pre swearing as she becomes more dehydrated

✅ I can't remember which book that's in, but I think it's Ares Express

> Human Furniture

❌ I'm drawing a blank on this, sorry.

However on the strength of everything else, I'm certain these are the books you're looking for.

Comment: . . . and now I need to read them both again, I genuinely thank you from the bottom of my heart 

Comment: Human furniture.... IIRC a bunch of girls (including the female lead) get caught by the "Furniture People" and are forced into compliance suits. These are like a tight black all over body stocking , they nano recycle all the waste products and liquids so the girls don't need fed or anything. The girls can't move from positions such as four of them kneeling on the floor supporting a large glass plate to make a table, for hours and hours.....I'm not sure if they were featured in either of those books, I think it was another book/author about a terraformed Mars

Comment: @DannyMcG I've not read the books, but a bit of Googling turned up [this review/discussion](https://www.lislelibrary.org/sciencefictionfantasy/our-discussion-ares-express) which suggests they're in *Ares Express*.  Which is interesting, because I know a few kink people who'd appreciate that part. :)